# How much was the engine moved in the B737 Max w.r.t. older versions?

Tags: boeing-737

In the wake of the sad [crash](https://avherald.com/h?article=4c534c4a&opt=1024) of ET-302, I am reading on multiple sources that

> the 737 Max's "engine is a bit further forward and a bit higher in relation to the wing, compared to the previous version of the plane. That affects the balance of the plane"

(from the [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-47514289))

Is there data available on how much these "bit further forward" and "bit higher" amount to?

In particular, to minimize misunderstandings, it would be ideal to know how much the CoG of the engines has moved w.r.t. the neutral point.

Comment: Without a better answer, you could try and estimate it using the scale drawings from the public Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning manuals: https://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/plan_manuals.page

Comment: Comparing the -800NG (https://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/commercial/airports/acaps/737.pdf page 39) and Max 8(https://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/commercial/airports/acaps/737MAX_RevC.pdf page 2-11), does not seem to be any significant change.

Comment: @DeepSpace I wouldn't know how to determine that from those figures, since the numbers are given w.r.t. something that changed for sure (the fuselage is longer, so the nose is further ahead) and the outlines are not required to be exactly to scale, I think.

Comment: @Federico There are scale drawings at the very end of the manuals...

Comment: @CptReynolds not really reliable if we are trying to determine changes in the centimetre range, right?

Comment: @Federico Of course. So... what exactly are you after? What effects would 15cm up have as opposed to 25cm up?

Comment: @CptReynolds I'm after the exact numbers, as stated in the question, not "a bit" or "about x cm".

Comment: @Federico I understand. I just wanted to also understand what the exact numbers would mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boeing [737-800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation#Specifications) and [737 MAX 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_MAX#Specifications) both have the exact same fuselage length of $ 39.47 \, \mathrm{m} $, so I chose these two models for comparison.

Boeing [publishes CAD drawings](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/3_view.page) for all aircraft models. I used the two CAD files for the 800 and MAX 8 to compare the engine size and location:

[image: 737-800]
[image: 737 MAX 8]

Since I do not know the units used in the CAD files, I used the known total fuselage length to scale the numbers:

- Distance from the nose to the front of the engine nacelle:

$$ \text{737-800:} \; 13.544 \, \mathrm{m} \; , \; \; \text{737 MAX 8:} \; 13.180 \, \mathrm{m} $$

- Length of the engine nacelle including exhaust:

$$ \text{737-800:} \; 5.075 \, \mathrm{m} \; , \; \; \text{737 MAX 8:} \; 5.345 \, \mathrm{m} $$

- Diameter of the engine nacelle:

$$ \text{737-800:} \; 1.978 \, \mathrm{m} \; , \; \; \text{737 MAX 8:} \; 2.407 \, \mathrm{m} $$

- Distance from the top of the engine nacelle to the bottom of the fuselage:

$$ \text{737-800:} \; 1.359 \, \mathrm{m} \; , \; \; \text{737 MAX 8:} \; 1.554 \, \mathrm{m} $$

Based on these measurements, the new engine nacelles are $ 270 \, \mathrm{mm} $ longer and have a $ 429 \, \mathrm{mm} $ larger diameter. They start $ 364 \, \mathrm{mm} $ further forwards and the top is $ 195 \, \mathrm{mm} $ higher.

Therefore, the center (geometric, not necessarily center of gravity) of the engines has moved $ 229 \, \mathrm{mm} $ forwards and $ 19 \, \mathrm{mm} $ *downwards*. While the geometric center may have moved downwards, the center of gravity probably moved upwards because the old nacelle was not symmetric (flattened at the bottom).

Comment: The dimensions given are in inches.

Comment: From the drawings it looks like the radome is a bit more elongated in the MAX version, as well as the tail cone. I'll accept these numbers for the moment anyway.